# React Native onPanResponderMove seems to be called too rarely

Tags: javascript, android, ios, typescript, react-native

I'm trying to implement a custom, vertical slider in `React Native`. For this purpose, I'm using a `PanResponder`. Since the slider is vertical, I'm changing the `y` value only. To stop the object on slider's borders I'm checking if it has reached any before calling `Animated.event`.

My slider works fine until I swipe the object very fast. Then `onPanResponderMove` callback seems to be called too rarely and the object stops outside the track, further than the border.

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.panResponder = PanResponder.create({
        onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
        onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => true,
        onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
        onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => true,
        onPanResponderGrant: this._handleOnPanResponderGrant.bind(this),
        onPanResponderMove: this._handleOnPanResponderMove.bind(this),
        onPanResponderRelease: this._handleOnPanResponderRelease.bind(this)
    })
}

_handleOnPanResponderGrant() {
    this.state.pan.setOffset({ x: this.state.pan.x._value, y: this.state.pan.y._value })
    this.state.pan.setValue({ x: 0, y: 0 })
}

_handleOnPanResponderMove(e, gestureState) {
    // some calculations - seems to be correct since everything is working fine until I swipe very fast
    if (reachedBorders(...)) { // this takes into account also the direction so it won't get stuck on the border
        return true
    }
    return Animated.event([null, { dy: this.state.pan.y }])(e, gestureState)
}

_handleOnPanResponderRelease() {
    this.state.pan.flattenOffset()
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is my approach correct (skipping `Animated.event` if outside the slider)?

**UPDATE:**

Probably the problem is that you can't stop the `PanResponder` move immediately during the gesture as described in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11248).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to prevent `PanResponder` from updating the `pan.y` value, you could have the consumer of the `pan` value use an `interpolated` value instead.  For example, if the borders were at `10` and `250`, you might use something like:

```
... style={{transform: [{translateY: this.state.pan.y.interpolate({
       inputRange: [10, 250],
       outputRange: [10, 250],
       extrapolate: 'clamp'
     })}]}}
```

In the `Release` method you would also need to clamp the values to within the borders, but the interpolate will prevent the animation from going too far.